# .bash_profile not read over parallel ssh connection (hss)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, bash

I'm using `hss` (https://github.com/six-ddc/hss) to connect to 3 Ubuntu servers (the same edition). The problem is on 2 of them `~/.bash_profile` is not read over `hss`, even though it is being read when I ssh in individually to each.

```
$ env | grep -w PATH
[O] root@example-sql -> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
[O] root@example-www -> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
[O] root@example-search -> PATH=.:/root/bin:/usr/local/node/bin:...
```

`example-search` does read `.bash_profile` apparently, because there are additional directories that I added to `PATH`, like `/root/bin`, etc. The first two, however, do not seem to.

Why is that happening? How can I fix that (I want `PATH` the way I defined it, obviously).

**UPDATE**

I have checked for sourcing `~/.bashrc` by adding `touch /tmp/something` on 'problem' host and then running some commands over `hss`. It does **NOT** source `.bashrc` on first 2 hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Executing a command remotely over `ssh` (or, in this case with `hss`), does **NOT** create an interactive login shell. This means that it will **not** read `.bash_profile`, but it **DOES** use `.bashrc`.

I think you should look at `.bashrc` on your three hosts and see if there are differences. Perhaps `.bashrc` on that host is also sourcing `.bash_profile`? Or, the PATH you are looking for is already in `.bashrc` on that one host?

Comment: That's the problem, I *have* checked for sourcing `.bash_profile` before. At the end of each `~/.bashrc` I DO have `. ~/.bash_profile` on each host. Then it could mean that `.bashrc` is not sourced, but why?

Comment: See UPDATE - apparently .bashrc does not get sourced. Why?

Comment: sounds like this is an issue with hss itself. Can you verify whether you have a TTY ?

Comment: When I tried using `hss`, it sourced `.bashrc` OK.